# How can I use the "plain" PKCE code challenge method with AppAuth?

Tags: android, ios, appauth, pkce

By default, [AppAuth](http://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS) sends a `S256` [PKCE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636) code challenge on auth requests. If I need to interoperate with a server that only supports the `plain` code challenge method, how can I configure my authorization request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**iOS**: You can override the PKCE parameters by using the [`OIDAuthorizationRequest initWithConfiguration:clientId:scope:redirectURL:responseType:state:codeVerifier:codeChallenge:codeChallengeMethod:additionalParameters:`](https://openid.github.io/AppAuth-iOS/docs/latest/interface_o_i_d_authorization_request.html#acf5c56d5c9fab96693433e82cb9bdcc4) constructor. This can be used to send a custom PKCE method (the library only supports `S256`).

```
// builds authentication request
NSString *codeVerifier = [OIDAuthorizationRequest generateCodeVerifier];
OIDAuthorizationRequest *request =
    [[OIDAuthorizationRequest alloc] initWithConfiguration:configuration
                    clientId:kClientID
                      scope:@"openid profile"
                 redirectURL:redirectURI
                responseType:OIDResponseTypeCode
                       state:[OIDAuthorizationRequest generateState]
                codeVerifier:codeVerifier
               codeChallenge:codeVerifier
         codeChallengeMethod:@"plain"
        additionalParameters:nil];
```

**Android**: You can override the PKCE parameters by adding [`setCodeVerifier(String, String, String)`](https://openid.github.io/AppAuth-Android/docs/latest/net/openid/appauth/AuthorizationRequest.Builder.html#setCodeVerifier-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) to your builder. This can be used to send a custom PKCE method (by default the library uses `S256` on clients that have SHA-256 platform support).

```
import net.openid.appauth.CodeVerifierUtil;

String codeVerifier = CodeVerifierUtil.generateRandomCodeVerifier();
AuthorizationRequest authRequest = new AuthorizationRequest.Builder(
    serviceConfig,
    CLIENT_ID,
    AuthorizationRequest.RESPONSE_TYPE_CODE,
    REDIRECT_URI)
    .setScope(SCOPE)
    .setCodeVerifier(codeVerifier, codeVerifier, "plain")
    .build();
```